# "npm install" downloads only old 1.0.0 version

Tags: npm, package.json

I just recently published my first npm package. When I try to install the package, it always downloads 1.0.0 version despite the major version is already 2 and npmjs.com shows the correct version.

Also npm adds the package in `package.json` dependencies as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "module_name": "file:module_name"
}
```

while the version of the module was expected. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had a directory within the project with the same name as the module has. Well, it is the old directory where I started to write the module and forgot to remove after moving the module project. It contained own `package.json` file and of course coinciding with the module name.

So, npm kept including the local module instead of the published. After renaming the directory (I am gonna remove it) it worked normally.